# replace camlp4 with camlp5 in utop

Tags: ocaml, camlp4, ocamlfind, utop

I'm working with OCaml code that needs [camlp5](http://camlp5.gforge.inria.fr/doc/html/); however, the toplevel (I'm using [utop](https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/about-utop/)) automatically loads the newer, incompatible camlp4. These are the startup messages:

```
Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
   #require "package";;      to load a package
   #list;;                   to list the available packages
   #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
   #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
   #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
   Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
   #thread;;                 to enable threads
```

The `.ocamlinit` im using looks like this:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
```

I installed `camlp5` with `opam` and it shows up when I issue `ocamlfind list`; also the file `camlp5.cma` is located in `/home/<username>/.opam/4.02.1/lib/camlp5/camlp5.cma`.
But trying to load `camlp5o` and `camlp5r` fails with `Unknown directive camlp5o`.

How can i make `utop` aware of `camlp5` and how can I replace `camlp4` with `camlp5` as the default preprocessor?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So you basically add #require "campl5" to your `.ocamlinit`, that should work :D

Comment: how does one install `camlp5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ ocaml
    OCaml version 4.02.1

Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

# #require "camlp5";;
/home/kakadu/.opam/4.02.1/lib/camlp5: added to search path
# #load "camlp5o.cma";;
    Camlp5 parsing version 6.12

#
```